# How to align elements in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm new in bootstrap how to put the logout link in the same line with picture and text
thanks

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between">
        <h4 class="navbar-brand">
          Hello {{std_name}} Your rate is: {{std_rate}}
          <img src="{% static 'images/star.png' %}" />
        </h4>
        <a href="" class="mr-sm-2" style="color: white">logout</a>
</nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `align-items-center` class in `nav` to center it vertically.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <h4 class="navbar-brand">
    Hello {{std_name}} Your rate is: {{std_rate}}
    <img src="{% static 'images/star.png' %}" />
  </h4>
  <a href="" class="mr-sm-2" style="color: white">logout</a>
</nav>
```